# What is the system log and where is it?

Tags: rules

at admin/config/workflow/rules/settings one can configure settings for logging related to rules and it states that: "Evaluations errors are logged to the system log".  What and where exactly is the 'system log'?

Comment: Likely the watchdog at /admin/reports/dblog

Comment: thanks, but is it likely or for sure?  can anyone confirm?

Comment: You can. Go to that path, and see if that's the right log. Let us know the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the logs are saved at `/admin/reports/dblog` for which the `dblog` module in the core is responsible. More about `dblog` : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/dblog/overview

You can also have the logs stored on the file system by enabling the `syslog` module (also in core). More about `syslog` : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/syslog/overview

It is recommended that you should not use the dblog module if you need to log messages more frequently as it does a write operation to the database.